# Limit the number of csv rows processed

Tags: php

I have a small script which processes CSVs and outputs another CSV.

I wanted to include an optional limiter to stop processing the CSV at the desired limiter.

I have tried a `do while` and this `for loop` and neither work.

The csv is always every row not the csv limit value?

```
  public function get_csv($csv_limit)
  {
    $file = fopen($this->csv_url, "r");
    $rows = [];
    $idsColumnsWanted = array_flip(array_keys($this->csv_headers));
    $skip_header = 0;
    
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $csv_limit; $i++)
    {
      while (false !== $fields = fgetcsv($file)) {
        if ($skip_header == 0) {
          $skip_header++;
          continue;
        }
        $this->csv_rows[] = array_intersect_key($fields, $idsColumnsWanted);
      }
    }

    fclose($file);
  }
```

Here is my make csv method also.

```
  public function make_csv()
  {
    $csv_file_name = $this->csv_file_name . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s",time()) . ".csv";
    $csv_init = fopen($csv_file_name, "w");
    
    fputcsv($csv_init, $this->csv_headers, ",", '"');
    
    foreach ($this->csv_rows as $row) {
      fputcsv($csv_init, $row);
    }
    
    fclose($csv_init);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
  public function get_csv($csv_limit)
  {
    $file = fopen($this->csv_url, "r");
    $rows = [];
    $idsColumnsWanted = array_flip(array_keys($this->csv_headers));
    
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $csv_limit; $i++)
    {
      $fields = fgetcsv($file);
      if ($fields === false) break;
      if ($i === 0) continue;
      $this->csv_rows[] = array_intersect_key($fields, $idsColumnsWanted);

    }

    fclose($file);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop, you then go on and use a `while` loop to read all of the rows...

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $csv_limit; $i++)
{
  while (false !== $fields = fgetcsv($file)) {  // This reads the entire file
  }
}
```

Instead you can just use the while loop, but count the lines being output...

```
$rowCount=0;
while ((false !== $fields = fgetcsv($file)) && $csv_limit > $rowCount++) {
    if ($skip_header == 0) {
        $skip_header++;
        continue;
    }
    $this->csv_rows[] = array_intersect_key($fields, $idsColumnsWanted);
}
```

Comment: thank you for support, I learnt a lot from your snippet, much appreciated.